# Same id for jQuery component is creating problem

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating one progress bar with jQuery but problem is this that i am connecting JQuery with id of component but as soon as i create new component with same id ,It does not work.What is the way to solve it?
I am attaching my HTML code & CSS. All other files are common jQUERY Library.

```
<body>
<script >
$(function(){

    $("#status").animate( { width: "80%" }, 2000);

});
</script>

<div id="progress-bar">
   <div id="status"  ></div>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar">
   <div id="status" ></div>
</div>
```

**CSS File**

```
#progress-bar {
    border: 2px outset #FFFFFF;
    background: #E1C555;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#status {
    background: #EC1414;
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to use the same ID twice.

You ***must*** use unique IDs or classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one html element with a given id. That is the *id must be unique*. Use classes if you want multiple html elements to be selected with the same name.

With your code:

```
<script >
$(function(){

    $(".status").animate( { width: "80%" }, 2000);

});
</script>

<div class="progress-bar">
   <div class="status"  ></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
   <div class="status" ></div>
</div>
```